# if, if else statement producin error message

Tags: javascript

I understand that each if statement and each if else statement is contained inside curly braces. That's what I've done here so far. I just started this code and I tested it with only 20% done so that I can fix errors before the code get's too long. With everything looking correct I'm getting a syntax error that for the life of me I can't see where it is. Any suggestions? Here is the code. And here is the link: [stickFigure](http://ciswebs.smc.edu/cis54/tyson_schweidel/stickFigure.htm)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>The mysterious road</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var curScene = 0

function changedScene(decision){
var message = "";

if(curScene==0) {
curScene=1;
message = "Let the games began!";
}
else if(curScene ==1){
if(decision==1){
    curScene = 2;
    message = "Looks like you're on the right road.";
}
else(curScene = 3);
message = "you're stading on a bridge overlooking a peaceful stream.";
}

document.getElementById("sceneimg"). src = "scene" + curScene + .png; //There's a syntax  error       here that I don't see!
alert(message);
}
</script>

<body>
<div style="margin-top:100px; text-align:center">
<p><img id="sceneimg" src="../sfa/scene0.png" alt="Stick Figure" /></p>

Enter here for a glorious adventure!
<input type="button" id="decision" value="1" onclick="curScene(1)" />
Enter this gate for the surpirse of your life!
<input type="button" id="decision" value="2" oonclick="curScene(2)" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks like your problem will be your `else` - as you said, it will expect curly braces not parentheses: `else { ... }`

Comment: `"scene" + curScene + .png` looks incorrect as well. I guess `.png` is supposed to be inside a string.

Comment: When you say inside a string, do you mean inside quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first syntax error you are aware of add say double quoats around the `".png"`

and you havent got got ant objects that support the method (no functions found) calling `curScene(1)` and your only function is `changedScene()` plus a typo with the `oonclick`. 
and what `fearofawhackplanet` said.

stick with it, dont give up

Answer (score 1):

Look here

`else(curScene = 3);`

and you should be able to work it out.

Comment: I see it now. So parentheses are for the if statement, not the else, right?

Comment: @swydell `( a expression can be placed within )`, for also like flow controls (if-else, switch) loops, loop control.

Comment: If there are more than 1 answer, why can't we accept multiple answers? I liked both answers and want to acknowledge that I accept the both. When one is checked, the other unchecks.

Answer (score 0):

Also, even though JavaScript allows it, you're missing a semicolon after your first script statement:

```
var curScene = 0
```

Be aware of such omissions. Even though it's not a syntax or semantics error here, this could get you into trouble elsewhere, such as (made up):

```
return  // return undefined
val1 + val2;
```

Because you use semicolons every where else to terminate your statements, it's best to be consistent.